# where filter with multiple operators in Weaviate

Tags: weaviate

I wonder is there is a way of querying inverted index by using complex logical operations, like:

```
find "some_text" from property 'property1' OR 'property2' AND created_at before 'date'
```

where filter only accepts one operator according to documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, it's explained [here](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/filters.html#where-filter)

An example based on your question would be:

```
{
  Get {
    ClassName(
      where: {
        operator: And
        operands: [{
          operator: Or
          operands: [{
            path: ["property"]
            operator: Like
            valueString: "property1"
          }, {
            path: ["property"]
            operator: Like
            valueString: "property2"
          }]
        }, {
          path: ["_creationTimeUnix"]
          operator: LessThan
          valueString: "1664505080008"
        }]
      }
    ) {
      property
      _additional {
        creationTimeUnix
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS:
This indeed becomes -as you write- a complex filter ;)

Comment: Somehow I missed the nested part... My bad. Thanks a lot for clarification.